# Tensorflow Serving With Object Detection

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to deploy a model based on Object Detection example to do some tests and I am getting this error:

"Expects arg[0] to be uint8 but float is provided"

In that case I am using this to load my data:

---

request.inputs['inputs'].CopyFrom(
        tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto({FLAGS.input_image}))

---

where FLAGS.input_image is my image data in bytes.

I was thinking that maybe that I should convert my image bytes to something that this input understands, but I haven't found yet.

What could I do to fix this issue?

Thanks !!!!

Comment: `uint8` is a common data format for images. Try converting your image before passing it to the request. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html

Answer (score 1):

To convert the image to bytes, use the following in client code (python)

```
with open(FLAGS.image, 'rb') as f:
     data = f.read()
```

Also please find a sample client (for inception model in python) as follows https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client.py

Comment: Also could you share the link of object detection example that you are following